# Reverse the sequence while keeping pairs of columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say my dataframe `df` has this sequence of columns:

```
['e', 'f', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
```

And I want to reverse the sequence while keeping pairs, resulting in this sequence:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

If the column names were always the same, I could use this same list above to generate the desired dataframe:

```
df = df[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']]
```

But if there can be multiple pairs of columns and without certainty of their names, the only certainty being that the last pair should come first and so on, how to proceed?

Comment: You can fetch the column names to a list, then rearrange that list in a simple Python loop, then feed that into your final statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
new_cols = df.columns.to_numpy().reshape(-1,2)[::-1].ravel()
print(df[new_cols])
```

Or since the `sorted` method is stable, you can reversely sort by the pair order:

```
n,N = 2,len(df.columns)
df.iloc[:, sorted(range(N), key=lambda x: x//n, reverse=True)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with [`pandas.Index.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.join.html):

```
rev = df.columns[::-1]  # reversed order of columns
df[rev[1::2].join(rev[::2], how='outer')]
```